# How to receive data from activity in android?

Tags: android

I want one sample code for startActivityForResult().
Please explain how it works?

Answer (score 1):

Look at [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/faq/commontasks.html#opennewscreen) documentation. You will get the result in onActivityResult() method.